# Magento 2.3.2 - Your password reset link has expired

Tags: magento2, password

I use **Magento 2.3.2**. If I request a password reset via the admin, I immediately receive an email with a reset link. If I click on it immediately, I get the message *"Your password reset link has expired"*.

If I request a password reset via the front of the website, I get the message *"We cannot send the password reset email."*

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem.
I use the Porto theme.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to change my custom theme (porto) file:
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Customer/templates/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml

and introduce new form param id like following:

```
['id' => $block->getRpCustomerId(), 'token' => $block->getRequest()->getParam("token")]
```